# Is it possible to customize ObjectMapper for single Spring Rest endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I know how to customize the default `ObjectMapper` bean. But for one specific Controller/endpoint, I'd like to use a different objectmapper. How can I do this?

I think my question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586645/is-it-possible-to-register-controller-specific-objectmapper-in-springboot) but there are no answers yet. Happy to get an answer there and mark this as duplicate

Comment: i tried to come up with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729997/592355)! xDxD (after 10 years) ..whereas the answer is "no" for the old question, i see a "probably" for yours! :) If you can structure your endpoints by  (java, media)"type" (which is "normal" in spring-data-rest), you can have custom objectmapper "per endpoint".

Comment: That's pretty smart, didn't know you could do that. I upvoted your answer. However, for my purposes, the object being returned is a `Map<String,Object>` and I don't know about changing the media-type. I didn't mention that this was for a graphql endpoint.

Comment: I ended up using a custom objectmapper to write the object as a string and changing the return type to String

Comment: thanks for the upvote! (i think it would also work with `Map`, but rather not generic types `<String, Object>`  ..i post my thoughts as answer..shortly;)

Comment: by "custom" you mean a `new`, local!? ... safe workaround!+1

Comment: by "custom", I just mean a different objectmapper than the default one injected by spring. In my particular case, it's actually wrapped in another object that's injected as a bean, but yeah, it could also have been a new local one.

Comment: Your solution might work for my Map as well, but I'm afraid of doing that in case there is another endpoint that also returns a Map

Comment: i get you, kane! :) what you can do in a github playground is maybe not that applicable in "real world"! ...post your solution! it is a "nice hack"!

Comment: posted my hack below

Answer (score 2):

There's a good solution by @xerx593 linked in the question's comments but I took a different approach for mine because I was returning a generic `Map<String,Object>` graphql return type and I didn't feel comfortable changing the media-type or applying the object mapper to all `Map`'s. I prefer their solution for the general case as it's more elegant

I simply serialized the return object as a string and returned it.

For example, I turned something like this

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Foo getFoo() {
  return new Foo();
}
```

to something like this

```
private ObjectMapper customMapper = ...;

@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getFoo() {
  return customMapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo());
}
```