# Prevent Spring from auto converting number string within json to Double

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a POST endpoint receiving json in the request body and is mapped to `Map<String, Object>`.

The value can be of any string format, I am OK for Spring to auto convert `"true"` or `"false"` to `Boolean`, `"123"` to `Integer`. But I do not like it to convert `"123.456"` to `Double`, I want it to leave it as is (`String`).

Is there any way (preferably config in application.yml) to selectively stop Spring from auto converting number string in json to `Double` only?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop" ? Ignore/big decimal/String/...? (...`@JsonIgnore`/`DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS`/https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: @xerx593 I mean I want it to leave it as is (`String`).

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695180/is-it-possible-to-customize-objectmapper-for-single-spring-rest-endpoint

Comment: Can you provide the code of your POST endpoint? Which version of Spring/Boot are you using?

Comment: why didn't you create a DTO instead of Map<String, Object> for request body.  Like that the attribute that will contain the value "123.456" could be a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the annotation @JsonDeserialize for Jackson.

Here follows an example model class that wraps the payload Map<String,Object> field and a controller class and the JSON deserialization class with the logic to accomplish what you want:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import za.co.twentysevenfour.excel.model.converter.ObjectMapDeserializer;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestPayloadWrapper implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ObjectMapDeserializer.class)
    private Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();

    public TestPayloadWrapper() {}

    public Map<String, Object> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(Map<String, Object> payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import za.co.twentysevenfour.excel.model.jpa.TestPayloadWrapper;
    
import java.util.Map;
        
        
@RestController
public class PayloadController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/postEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> postEndpoint(@RequestBody TestPayloadWrapper payload) 
    {
        return payload.getPayload();
    }
}
```

JsonDeserializer class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ObjectMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String,Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String,Object> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        ObjectNode objectNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        objectNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(field -> {
            JsonNode fieldValue = objectNode.get(field);
            if(fieldValue.isBoolean()) {
                result.put(field,fieldValue.asBoolean());
            } else if(fieldValue.isInt()) {
                result.put(field,fieldValue.asInt());
            } else if(fieldValue.isLong()) {
                result.put(field,fieldValue.asLong());
            } else if(fieldValue.isDouble()) {
                // Here you set the double as a string
                result.put(field,fieldValue.asText());
            } else {
                result.put(field,fieldValue.asText());
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is not the prettiest of solutions, this is the only one I know, I guess you will need to extend and modify the deserializer class somewhat to cater for all value types but at least this gives you a solid example of how to do it for a specific field, I tested this and it works.

I however would suggest you always know the type of the values you will receive but I fully understand there will be certain scenarios where this might not be so.

The test json payload I used is as follow:

```
{
    "payload" : { "testDouble" : 1.40 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would probably be to change it to a Map<String, String> and do you own conversions where you want it. I know you are okay with Boolean, but it is probably better here to go back to the ground state for all options, and re-introduce the wanted ones than to exclude a single option.

Answer (score 1):

I won't suggest the below particulary for your case. As you just need to disable the auto conversion of "123.56" or something like that but keep as like it is for others. Since the following property disables for all.

> spring.jackson.mapper.allow-coercion-of-scalars=false

I don't think their is a specific config in properties file for that. If there is please let me know too. What I can suggest is either create a custom configuraion and create a bean for ObjectMapper and create a custom module for serialization which can do that don't overwrite other configs.

It may look something like:

```
@Configuration public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Create a module for custom serialization
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Double.class, ToStringSerializer.instance);
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Or else you can do an easy idea. Just take everthing as String and manually convert by parsing later. If you have just few fields you can use this idea.

Comment: This is a not good way to override the default `ObjectMapper` bean, since Spring can customize it with a lot of things. It's better to use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` instead. [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper) explain this very clearly