# Use JsonSerialize for java types at class level

Tags: java, spring, jackson, decimalformat

I have a class `Response` with multiple `Double` values in it. It looks something like below.

```
class Data {
   private Double number1;
   private Double number2;
   private Double number3;
   private Double number4;

   //Getters and Setters ... 

}
```

I want use this class to send a response for a Spring rest service, however I need to format the `Double` values in a specific way (something like `23,45,276.10` ).

I can achieve this by changing the types to String and setting them via `java.text.DecimalFormat` or via using `JsonSerialize` annotation at each field.

But is there a way where I can **define this at class level**, or better yet at request level? Annotating every single `Double` variable is something I would want to avoid.

Like some kind of global or class level configuration/annotation that can help me convert all `Double` elements into a specific format?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically register your serializer as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper serializingObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Double.class, new YourDoubleSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

This would be applied to all `Double` properties in your classes when they are serialized. Doing this at the request level I don't think it is possible.

Comment: That's good but also a little troublesome, you see there are other API endpoints that I probably would not want to affect. May be there could be a way to configure this bean for a specific endpoint or path?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. A quick search online led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729997/16572295, which shows a workaround, but I am not entirely sure this would be better than simply annotating the desired properties or using my suggestion.