# How to add new ObjectMapper in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, objectmapper

In my Spring Boot project I use a default Jackson ObjectMapper. I'd like to add new ObjectMapper to the Spring Context and start using it at new places, but also keep the default one. Adding new @Bean definition will override the default ObjectMapper. How can I add new ObjectMapper Bean without overriding the former one?

Comment: Simplest solution/workaround: create a "wrapper" (bean) for additional om's. A built-in "wrapper" (which is used by `@requestMapping`) is `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (bean)...you can have a "default" om additionally *per java type* a map of media type to om's... [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66586645/592355)

Comment: What do you mean by creating new ObjectMapper bean it would replace the default one?

Comment: Spring Boot autoconfiguration usually creates default Beans which are overridden when you create your own one of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is [hard-impossible] to hack. With a simple trick (asian philosophy), we can circumvent the problem/make it no problem at all:

Wrap your (1+, auto configured, `@ConditionalOnMissing...`) bean in something else/custom/a "wrapper". (at the costs of: referring to 1+/thinking about the difference/more complexity)

Mentioned [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) ([auto-config here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.java)) has this (built-in) capability (& purpose) to map to multiple object mappers in terms of "http conversion".

So with a (generic, e.g. java.util.Map based) thing like:

```
class MyWrapper<K, V> {
  final Map<K, V> map;
  public MyWrapper(Map<K, V> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }
  public Map<K, V> getMap() {
    return map;
  }
}
```

We can go wire it:

```java
@Bean
MyWrapper<String, ObjectMapper> myStr2OMWrapper(/*ObjectMapper jacksonOm*/) {
  return new MyWrapper(Map.of(
      // DEFAULT, jacksonOm,
      "foo", fooMapper(), 
      "bar", barMapper()
  ));
}
```

..where `fooMapper()` and `barMapper()` can refer to (static/instance) *no-bean* methods:

```java
private static ObjectMapper fooMapper() {
  return new ObjectMapper()
      .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true) // just a demo...
      .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); // configure/set  as see fit...
}
private static ObjectMapper barMapper() {
  return new ObjectMapper()
      .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false) // just a demo...
      .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false); // configure/set more...
}
```

(Already) testing/using time:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoAppTests {

  @Autowired
  MyWrapper<String, ObjectMapper> my;
  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper jacksonOM;

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
    System.err.println(jacksonOM);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(jacksonOM);
    my.getMap().entrySet().forEach(e -> {
      System.err.println(e);
      Assertions.assertNotNull(e.getValue());
    });
  }
}
```

Prints (e.g.)

```bash
...
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@481b2f10
bar=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@577bf0aa
foo=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@7455dacb
...
Results:

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
...
```

Sorry this test dosn't verify (individual) configuration, but only:  (visually different) not null object mappers.

---

How to enable (multiple!) [`my.custom.jackson.*`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonProperties.java) auto configuration, is a more complex question... (it is not as easy as e.g. `my.custom.datasource.*` config ;(

With:

```
@Bean
@Primary // ! for auto config, we need one primary (whether it is "spring.jackson"  ... adjust;)
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.jackson")
JacksonProperties springJacksonProps() {
  return new JacksonProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("foo.jackson")
JacksonProperties fooProps() {
  return new JacksonProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("bar.jackson")
JacksonProperties barProps() {
  return new JacksonProperties();
}
```

we can already load and differentiate (full blown) config like:

```properties
spring.jackson.locale=en_US
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
# ... all of spring.jackson @see org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties
foo.jackson.locale=en_US
foo.jackson.time-zone=PST
# ... just for demo purpose
bar.jackson.locale=de_DE
bar.jackson.time-zone=GMT+1
```

And also (no problem) pass them (props) to the according (static `[foo|bar]Mapper`) methods.... but then? (If you are good with it, you can stop reading here!:)

Unfortunately the [according ("state of art") code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L183-L341) (to wire `JacksonProperties` with "om builder") is not public (i.e. not extendable/pluggable).

Instead the auto configuration provides (if none defined/`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`):

- a *prototype* `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean, which (everytime when requested):

  - applies (i.e. receives) customization from all (known) `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` beans.
  - of which [one (auto configured, order(0), package private) is the "standard"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L183-L341) responsible for wiring (spring.jackson.* only) `JacksonProperties` to `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`...

So the the simplest approach seems (up-to-date) to:

- steel/adopt [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L183-L341) (not-/implementing `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`)
- construct (from "stolen" + properties) according builders/mappers, as see fit.

e.g. (review+TEST before PROD!) non-interface, returns a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, mimic the auto-configured, without applying (other) customizers/-ation:

```java
// ...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module; // !! not java.lang.Module ;)
// ...
private static class MyStolenCustomizer {

  private final JacksonProperties jacksonProperties;
  private final Collection<Module> modules;
  // additionally need/want this:
  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  // copy/adopt from spring-boot:
  private static final Map<?, Boolean> FEATURE_DEFAULTS = Map.of(
      SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false,
      SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false
  );

  public MyStolenCustomizer(
    ApplicationContext applicationContext,
    JacksonProperties jacksonProperties,
    Collection<Module> modules
  ) {
      this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
      this.jacksonProperties = jacksonProperties;
      this.modules = modules;
  }
  // changed method signature!!
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder buildCustom() {
    // mimic original (spring-boot) bean:
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.applicationContext(applicationContext);
    // without (additional!) customizers:
    if (this.jacksonProperties.getDefaultPropertyInclusion() != null) {
      builder.serializationInclusion(this.jacksonProperties.getDefaultPropertyInclusion());
    }
    if (this.jacksonProperties.getTimeZone() != null) {
      builder.timeZone(this.jacksonProperties.getTimeZone());
    }
    configureFeatures(builder, FEATURE_DEFAULTS);
    configureVisibility(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getVisibility());
    configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getDeserialization());
    configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getSerialization());
    configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getMapper());
    configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getParser());
    configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getGenerator());
    configureDateFormat(builder);
    configurePropertyNamingStrategy(builder);
    configureModules(builder);
    configureLocale(builder);
    configureDefaultLeniency(builder);
    configureConstructorDetector(builder);
    // custom api:
    return builder; // ..alternatively: builder.build();
  }
  // ... rest as in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L223-L341
```

To wire `modules`, we can (hopefully, as originally) rely on:

```java
@Autowired
ObjectProvider<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module> modules
```

To initialize them like:

```java
@Bean
MyStolenCustomizer fooCustomizer(ApplicationContext context, @Qualifier("fooProps") JacksonProperties fooProperties, ObjectProvider<Module> modules) {
  return new MyStolenCustomizer(context, fooProperties, modules.stream().toList());
}

@Bean
MyStolenCustomizer barCustomizer(ApplicationContext context, @Qualifier("barProps") JacksonProperties barProperties, ObjectProvider<Module> modules) {
  return new MyStolenCustomizer(context, barProperties, modules.stream().toList());
}
```

..and use them like:

```java
@Bean
MyWrapper<String, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder> myStr2OMBuilderWrapper(
    @Qualifier("fooCustomizer") MyStolenCustomizer fooCustomizer,
    @Qualifier("barCustomizer") MyStolenCustomizer barCustomizer) {
  return new MyWrapper(
      Map.of(
          "foo", fooCustomizer.buildCustom(),
          "bar", barCustomizer.buildCustom()
      )
  );
}
```

...avoiding "double customization"/leaving `JacksonAutoConfiguration` enabled/intact/active.

Problem: time/updates(/external code)!

Answer (score 2):

If you want just a default ObjectMapper to use, I wrote a small utility that has some static methods for serializing/deserializing JSON and it uses ObjectMapper inside. You don't have to inject any beans. just use the Util. Here is Javadoc for the [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class. It comes with the java Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. You can get it as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or in [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest and cleanest way is to create you own object mapper instead of default one, using spring-configured builder:

```
@Bean
fun objectMapper(builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder): ObjectMapper {
    return builder.build()
}
```

That will create an object mapper that is exactly the same as if it was created by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, just faced a similar problem - I had already figured out how to make a new ObjectMapper bean, but I couldn't figure out, no matter what I did, how to keep that from Spring Boot's auto-configuration (so that it would continue to make the default one). In the end, I gave up and simply made the second bean (mimicking the default one), myself. I chose to name it, hopefully to avoid any collision, and to declare it @Primary, to be chosen as would have the default.

In either case, making an ObjectMapper is quite easy, as such:

```
    @Bean("standardJsonObjectMapper") // named, though not necessary
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary // mimic default
    public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper standardJsonObjectMapper() {
        return
            org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
                .json()
                .build();
    }
```

That builder has MANY functions available for customization (like `failOnUnknownProperties(boolean)` and `featuresToEnable(Object...)`) - just choose the ones you want, and off you go!